# Does a line with “video:24803kB audio:945kB…” indicate a successful conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg

I redirect the output during ffmpeg conversion into txt files and I noticed that after multiple lines, it shows the progress. For example:

```
frame= 867 fps= 18 q=29.0 q=31.0 size= 17846kB time=00:00:28.96 bitrate=5047.6kbits/s
frame= 879 fps= 18 q=29.0 q=31.0 size= 18012kB time=00:00:29.36 bitrate=5025.3kbits/s
frame= 890 fps= 18 q=29.0 q=31.0 size= 18175kB time=00:00:29.72 bitrate=5008.0kbits/s
frame= 900 fps= 18 q=29.0 q=31.0 size= 18429kB time=00:00:30.06 bitrate=5021.8kbits/s
frame= 901 fps= 17 q=-1.0 Lq=31.0 size= 20219kB time=00:00:30.14 bitrate=5494.6kbits/s
```

Every time, it outputs a line of this type:

```
video:24803kB audio:945kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 21.473556%
```

Is this a safe clue to know whether the conversion completed successfully? Or could the above line also appear in the case of a failed conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that line is only shown when the encoding of video and audio is finished and the bitstreams have been merged ("muxed") into the container format.

Of course, there could have been minor errors during the conversion such as incorrect timestamps, missing packets in case of an RTP stream as input, et cetera. But in general, it's safe to say that conversion has stopped when this line appears.

You could also inspect the

```
frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      12kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=  50.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
```

line for frame count or timestamp, since you'll probably know how many frames or what time your output video should have.